# ASAN doesn't report memory leak for glib's GPtrArray related functions

Tags: clang, glib, address-sanitizer

I find `ASAN` doesn't report memory leak for [glib](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib)'s `GPtrArray` related functions. For example:

```
$ cat test_asan.c
#include <glib.h>
int main()
{
    GPtrArray *gparray = g_ptr_array_new_with_free_func(g_free);

    g_ptr_array_add(gparray, g_strdup("--"));
}
```

Build and run this file:

```
$ clang -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -fsanitize=address -g test_asan.c -o test_asan -lglib-2.0
$ ./test_asan
$
```

Nothing is reported. But in fact, the above program forget to call `g_ptr_array_free (gparray, TRUE);` at the end of `main` function.

Anyone can give some explanation of this behaviour? Or I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

LeakSanitizer is using a [simple algorithm](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerLeakSanitizerDesignDocument) which scans stack frames, registers, global and thread-local variables and reachable heap allocations for data which looks like memory addresses. This happens without compiler feedback so unrelated, random or stale data may cause lost memory to be considered reachable. The algorithm is thus imprecise and is known to generate false negatives (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/937) or [here](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1021)) which in practice depend on compiler/library version and/or flags.

Usually issues like the one you describe happen when stale contents of `main`'s frame (`gparray` in your case) happens to not be overwritten when LSan scan starts.

As this a design issue, there isn't much you can do about it.